# Creating Blog Post Archive In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, archive

I am trying to allow a user to click on a month and have the posts for that month be listed (sort of like doing a search, but without the search form).  I want them to be able to just click the month name.

I can create an archive of the posts connected to certain months and have them displayed in the sidebar, but I want the posts for that month to replace the posts listed in the index action for the posts.

Here is the code I am using for the archive currently...

In the Posts Controller...

def index

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC")
@recent_posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
@posts_by_month = Post.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC").group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B %Y")}

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
end
```

end

Here is what is in the corresponding index view...

blog.archive

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>
<p class="month-archive"><%= monthname %></p>
     <div class="archive">
    <ul class="archive">
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <li class="archive"><p class="archive-post"><%= post.title %></p></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will list the posts based on the month they were created in, but this only gets me halfway there.  I want the user to be able to click on the month and have it show the entire posts, and not just a listing in the sidebar.

Hope that makes some sense.

Any help is appreciated.  I've tried finding an example somewhere to look at so that I can wrap my head around how to do it and have not been able to.

Thanks!

Aaron...newby to Ruby

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to create a new method something called 'month' in Posts controller, and also create a routing something like

```
match 'posts/month/:month' => 'Posts#month', :as=> posts_by_month
```

in a new method in Posts controller, you would use argument `params[:month]` to select the adequate articles with `:month=>params[:month]`

**edit**

In a view page, you would create each month to link to `posts/month/:month` where `:month` would be any month related string that you have chosen.

Also, it seems that you are fetching same data twice.. It seems that @posts and @recent_posts are doing the same job. You may want to eliminate one of them to improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will mess around with that and reply with where I can get.  Thanks again!

Comment: Would you mind selecting the answer then? You can do that by clicking the checkmark button right below the score up/down buttons.